# How to give my emacs access to ghostscript?

Tags: docview

I strugle to give my emacs access to ghostscript (to make doc-view show me pdf previews), and seem lost in a
plethora of internet advises about how to install gs. Here is what I have done, and
it does not work yet:

1. I have installed ghostscript at

C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.09\bin\gswin32.exe

2. I have set the environmental PATH to

   C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.09\bin
3. In my emacs init file I have the following code:

   (add-to-list 'load-path "C:/Program Files (x86)/gs/gs9.09/bin/")

   (add-to-list 'load-path "C:/Program Files (x86)/gs/gs9.09/lib/")

When I give the following shell command from emacs

```
 M-! gsview32
```

"gsview32" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

What is lacking in my setup above (and what is not needed)?

Comment: It probably should be `exec-path`, not `load-path`. Also, how exactly did you set environment variables (through Windows dialog, or by calling `setenv` in Emacs?). What shell are you running in Emacs (is it Cygwin's bash or cmd.exe?). If it is cmd.exe, what happens if you type in shell `where gsview32`?

Comment: Try this:  `(setq doc-view-ghostscript-program "/path/to/gs")`  In my experience, the `exec-path` is for things like helping Emacs to create the `*Completions*` buffer -- however, that is unrelated to helping Emacs find an executable to start a process as that relies upon the environmental variable for the `$PATH`.  You can see what your `$PATH` by typing:  `M-x eval-expression RET (getenv "PATH") RET`

Comment: I have tried both exec-path and load-path, but none of them made gsview32 active. my path were
C:\Program Files (x86)\emacs\emacs25093\bin 
C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.09\bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `doc-view-ghostscript-program` is customizable:

```lisp
(setq doc-view-ghostscript-program "C:/Program Files (x86)/gs/gs9.09/bin/gswin32.exe")
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but gsview is still dead, I get the same error-message as in my original question. Should I try ghostscript that I have in a Cygwin installation instead?

Comment: My answer will ensure that you can view a `pdf` file in `doc-view-mode` **IF** you have the required `dll` files needed to view `png` images on Emacs for Windows.  My answer does *not* attempt to set the `$PATH` variable in your Windows installation, or within Emacs.  If you want to execute shell-commands from within Emacs that are able to locate a particular executable on your hard drive, then you'll need to set the `$PATH` correctly -- either in Widows system variables or within Emacs.  If your ultimate goal is to view `pdf` files in Emacs in `doc-view-mode`, then this answer suffices.

Comment: yes now it works! :) nice, I can preview both pdf and doc files! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Pdf files are visible nicely, but not doc or odt files. Is it possible to make them visible too?

Comment: I'm working on testing my comment on your previous thread about preview, which is to hit the space bar on any file in dired-mode and have a little window pop-up showing a human readable image of a variety of files.  I liked the description of the free program `seer`, but it requires Window Vista or greater.  I have been using Windows XP within a virtual container (Parallels) on OSX to build Emacs for Windows and play with it.  I'm building a new Emacs master branch this morning, and am installing Windows 7 in a virtual container.  But I have work-related stuff to do also today. . . .

Comment: I do not know if there is any existing Emacs library that can create an Emacs buffer containing a human readable preview of MS Word and OpenOfficeOrg files.  [I suspect not, but perhaps some Googling by someone like you might be able to find an Emacs library that we can try out.  :)]  The idea about using something like `seer` is that I hope it will be a quick pop-up window using that third-party program -- space-bar to pop it up and space-bar to close it again.  That idea is just using Emacs to launch a process for the external program.

Comment: "DocView mode is a major mode for viewing DVI, PostScript (PS), PDF, OpenDocument, and Microsoft Office documents"

source:
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Document-View.html

so.. how to tell doc-view to preview my odt and doc files?

Comment: I use peep-dired today, and it has a very nice pop-up window showing my png, jpg, and now, pdf files.

Comment: Hmm ...  I wasn't aware of all that -- thank you.  A quick Google led me to:  "*For OpenDocument and Microsoft Office documents, the ‘unoconv’ tool is needed.*"  I'll need to research how to install and configure that on OSX.  I do not know if there is a Windows equivalent of `unoconv` -- that would be the next step . . . -- i.e., install that tool and then see if there is an option to configure the path to the executable within `doc-view-mode`.

Comment: Can you give me that url?

Comment: The language in the page that I Googled on Emacs wiki matches footnote 14 of the manual that you cited a few comments above.